# MongoDB embedded document update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The User schema has an embedded Watchlist schema that allows you to save a coin to the user. Then there's an option to update the coin with price alert parameters. The issue I'm running into is, I can easily update the parameters when I save one coin. After that, when I add in multiple coins, if I send an update to the backend, it wipes out all of the watchlist and just updates the one coin I'm adding params for.

````
  try {
    const coin = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          watchlist: {
            _id: req.body._id,
            name: req.body.name,
            upperLimit: req.body.upperLimit,
            lowerLimit: req.body.lowerLimit,
          },
        },
      },
      { returnDocument: "after" }
    );
    console.log(coin);
    const token = jwt.sign({ user: coin }, process.env.SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "24h",
    });
    console.log(coin, "this is the coin");
    res.status(200).json(token);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("coin update error", err);
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
}```

(to note: the req.params.id is the User's id. The req.body._id is the Watchlist id)
````

Answer (score 0):

Set upsert to True. By default Mongo tends to wipe out data.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/